# Why do homographies transform points contravariantly and lines covariantly?

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, computer-vision

In the context of projective spaces, a homography is the most general transform. In $\mathbb{P}^2$ (projective space of $\mathbb{R^2}$), a homography can be represented as a matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$, which, nevertheless, has only 8 degrees of freedom, because, intuitively, in homogeneous coordinates, points are equivalent up to a scalar multiplication. In $\mathbb{P}^2$, both points and lines can be represented as vectors, so a homography can transform both points and lines.

In the context of computer vision specifically, why do we say that homographies transform points *contravariantly* and lines *covariantly*? What does that mean?

I have the following two equations

$$
m = (H^{-1})^{T} l
$$

$$
\mathbf{x}' = H \mathbf{x}
$$

where $H$ is a homography matrix, $m$ and $l$ are lines and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{x}'$ are points in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Could this be the meaning of the expressions above? If yes, why exactly those expressions?

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly what it means. Write down the equation of a line, apply the homography to the point variable, and see what you get. This is not specific to computer vision.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function $f:\mathbb P^2 \rightarrow \mathbb P^2$ by $$f(x:y:z)=(x':y':z')$$ where
$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{bmatrix}=H\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$ Let $L$ be the line $\{(a:b:c)|la+mb+nc=0\}.$ The point $(x:y:z)$ is in $f(L)$ iff $$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y
\\z\end{bmatrix}=H\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$$ for some $(a:b:c) \in L.$
$$\begin{bmatrix}l&m&n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=[0]$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}l&m&n\end{bmatrix}H^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=[0]$$ Thus $f(L)$ is the line with equation $l'x+m'y+n'z=0$ where $$\begin{bmatrix}l'&m'&n'\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}l&m&n\end{bmatrix}H^{-1}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}l'\\m'\\n'\end{bmatrix}=(H^{-1})^T\begin{bmatrix}l\\m\\n\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more your formulas? I guess you're using the incidence relation, but then I don't get how you obtain the successive equation.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Hartley and Andrew Zisserman, in the book *Multiple view geometry in computer vision*, on page 36, say that points transform contravariantly and lines covariantly because, in one case, we use $H$ and, in the other, we use $H^{-1}$. They also talk about this, in the context of tensors, in Appendix 1 (page 562), but they don't apparently explain the origin of the expressions "covariant" and "contravariant". However, I found [this related Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors) that may be helpful.